Ignite External Storage and SQL Use
I am using Ignite 2.16.0.
I have postgres as my external persistence store and I have configured Ignite to be a read-through and write-through cache and have configured it in that manner.
Now I want to instantiate the cache and get data from the cache using "Select * from table limit 10" kind of queries. What I have seen is that this query only works if the data has been loaded from Postgres into the cache. If the data is not in the cache then it returns zero rows.
Is there a way I can run the query and get the data even if the data is not loaded into the cache?
Tried without loading the data into the cache

You need to load the data from your database into Ignite. More in the documentation.
Why does it work this way? Think about the query select * from table limit 10. It does not define which ten records to retrieve. To accurately respond to this query, you’d have to forward the query to Postgres, which defeats the point of using a cache.
